# Replace the second integer/number in a string

Tags: ruby

Given different Strings with each two Integers, what is the easiest way in Ruby (2.7) to replace the second Integer?

Example:

```rb
'We are there from 2 to 5 oclock'
'You can stack 15 onto 22 boxes'
```

So far I am using `string::gsup` but I am wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: Include your code, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsub` is the easiest way to achieve this job.

Input

```
a='We are there from 2 to 5 oclock'
```

Code

```
p a.gsub(/\D*\d+\D+\K\d+/,"10000")
```

Output

```
"We are there from 2 to 10000 oclock"
```